# Existence of pseudo-regular polygons

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, angle, polygons

A *regular polygon* is a bounded, not self-intersecting polygon in which all edges have the same length and all interior angles are identically, say, $\theta$.
It is known that $\theta=(1-2/n)\pi$ for some $n\ge 3$.

Now, define a *pseudo-regular polygon* as a bounded, not self-intersecting (but not necessarily convex) polygon in which all edges have the same length and all interior angles are $\in\{\theta,2\pi-\theta\}$ for some fixed $\theta<\pi$. All regular polygons are pseudo-regular, and there are others:

[image]

> **Question:** Are there any with $\theta\not=(1-2/n)\pi$ for all $n\ge 3$?

---

**Update**

Based on the comment of  nickgard, I found a solution and posted it as an asnwer.
It was surprisingly straight forward.

Comment: I would think about this problem as one about the finite sum of complex numbers of the form $e^{i\theta k}$ for some integers $k$, in which the sum equals zero.

Comment: My intuition is that you still need to make a closed circuit with a net turn of $2\pi$, so the same condition on $\theta$ will apply. Not immediately sure how to make this rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, there aren't any others.

The interior angle sum of a bounded, not self-intersecting but not necessarily convex $n$-gon is always $(n-2)\pi$.
Now, if there are $n_1$ vertices with interior angle $\theta$, and $n_2$ vertices with interior angle $2\pi-\theta$, we obtain

$$n_1\theta+n_2(2\pi-\theta)=(n_1+n_2-2)\pi.$$

This rearranges to

$$\theta=\Big(1-\frac2{n_1-n_2}\Big)\pi,$$

and so we see that $\theta$ *must* be the interior angle of a regular $n$-gon.

---

**Update**

I just realized that this this answer assumes that the pseudo-regular polygon is connected and simply connected (i.e. the boundary is connected).
Here is an example with $\theta=\pi/2$ that is not simply connected.

[image]

Anyway, my argument still holds.
One just has to apply the argument to each connected component and to each hole separately.